# Do I need to lock the table?

Tags: python, mysql

I use MySQL's default engine `innodb` and MySQL's default transaction `REPEATABLE READS`.

My table `Job` has two fields, `job_id` and `queue`. Here I have two tasks, the first task is to insert a record based on the max queue.

```
import uuid
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("conn_info")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT max(queue) from job")
max_queue = cursor.fetchone()[0]
job_id, queue = str(uuid.uuid1()), max_queue + 1
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO job VALUES(%s,%s)", (job_id, queue))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

The second task is to reduce every row's `queue` value by one.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("conn_info")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("UPDATE job SET queue = queue - 1")
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Here if two tasks happened at the same time. I want to make sure the second task executed after the first task. That's to say, first inserts a value then reduce the value of each row. In this case, do I have to add a `lock`? If the answer is yes, what kind of `lock` should I add?

Comment: What do you mean by "there might be some issue"? You are the one who should know what is and what isn't an issue. To me, it seems like this has an issue regardless of locking. The `queue` value of a newly inserted job depends on whether insert happens before or after `queue = queue - 1`. That cannot be good.

Comment: You have not provided any business context, so it is impossible to tell if anything here would cause a problem. Using max of queue to generate a new value is usually serialized (well, avoided in the first place), otherwise two concurrent transactions can retrieve the same max value and generate the same new queue value. If the queue value is used for ordering tasks for execution, then using a timestamp instead of an integer could be better. But again, we have absolutely no clue what you are using your task table for.

Comment: @haojie it is still unclear what you exactly want to accomplish! My guess is that your are greatly overcomplicating this exercise!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). Experiment with a test database to explore how this works. Open two windows with MySQL clients to your test database:

Window 1:

```
mysql> create table job ( job_id char(36), queue int, primary key (queue));

mysql> insert into job values (uuid(), 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> start transaction;

mysql> select max(queue) from job for update;
+------------+
| max(queue) |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

Don't commit in Window 1 yet, to simulate concurrent transactions.

Window 2:

```
mysql> select max(queue) from job for update;
<waits for lock>
```

Window 1:

```
mysql> insert into job values (uuid(), 1 + 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> commit;
```

Window 2:

The lock has been released, so it proceeds with its own locking read:

```
mysql> select max(queue) from job for update;
<ends wait>
+------------+
| max(queue) |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
```

Like the comments above, I also have questions about what you're trying to do, and whether there's an easier way (there probably is). My answer doesn't try to address that, it only addresses the question you asked about locking.

Comment: Thanks Karwin. Here I have a question, you only use `transaction` and `lock` for the first task. Do we need to use `transaction` and `lock` for the second table?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You mentioned only one table in your scenario, it's called `job`.

Comment: Yeah, only one table. But there are two tasks execute the table.

Comment: The other task is UPDATE, which is already a locking statement. It will acquire locks, and force concurrent sessions to wait.